# Mountain numbers

Tags: number-theory

This question is a follow-up to [a question that was asked on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391784/sieve-methods-and-primal-height) but downvoted there.

Define the primal order $\omega_{\mathbb{P}}(n)$ of an integer $n$ as the smallest integer $k$ such that the $k$-th iterate of the prime counting function $\pi$ evaluated at $n$ (that is $\pi\circ\pi\circ\cdots\pi$ with $k$ times $\pi$) is composite, and the primal height $h_{\mathbb{P}}(n)$ of $n$ as $\sum_{p\mid n}\omega_{\mathbb{P}}(p)$. Note that $\Omega(n)=k\Longrightarrow h_{\mathbb{P}}(n)\geqslant k$ where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$ counted with multiplicity.

Define now a mountain number of level $d$ as an integer $n$ such that $h_{\mathbb{P}}(n)=d\Omega(n)$. Note that every prime number, as well as any power thereof, is of course a mountain number.

Denoting by $\mathcal{M}_{d}(x)$ the number of mountain numbers of level $d$ not exceeding $x$, can one get an asymptotics for $\mathcal{M}_{d}(x)$?

Comment: @SylvainJulien FYI, when someone asks for citation, the best course of action is to edit that citation into the question itself.  Comments are intentionally ephemeral---key information needs to be included into the question.

Comment: With respect to your definition of the $k^{\text{th}}$ iterate of the prime counting function $\pi$, are you saying the first iterate is $\pi(n)$, the second iterate is $\pi(\pi(n))$, the third iterate is $\pi(\pi(\pi(n)))$, ... ?

Comment: With respect to a mountain number of level $d$, are you assuming $d$ is rationale or restricting $d$ to the integers? Using the definition of the $k^{\text{th}}$ iterate of the prime counting function $\pi$ in my previous comment your statement "every prime number, as well as any power thereof, is of course a mountain number" is only true if "d" is allowed to be rationale. If $d$ is allowed to be rationale, is there not a value of $d$ for which every integer greater than one is a mountain number?

Comment: Yes for the iterate. $d$ is assumed to be integral, which allows a prime  $p$ to be a mountain number since then $\Omega(p)=1$.

Comment: Ok, but $h_{\mathbb{P}}(8)=5$ and $\Omega (8)=3$, so the prime power $2^3=8$ is not a mountain number.

Comment: How do you get $h_{\mathbb{P}}(8)=5$? $\omega_{\mathbb{P}}(2)=1$, and $8=2\times 2\times 2$, so $h_{\mathbb{P}}(8)=3$.